# Randomly assign background colour for each frame

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, random-numbers

How can a randomly picked background colour be chosen for each beamer frame?

### Note:

This question is asked to round out the question [Randomly assign color to background in the PDF whenever page is turned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171340/36296) which asks for a solution which alters the colour when the `pdf` is displayed. On contrast the present question deals with randomly assigning colours during compilation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this in ConTeXt. To set the color of a page, we need:

```
\definebackgrounds[page][background=color, backgroundcolor=...name...]
```

At each page, the `setups` specified in `definebackgrounds` are re-evaluated. So, to change the color of each page, we can simply change the value of the background color to a random color. It is easier to do so in Lua. So, here is a complete example:

```
\startluacode
  local random = math.random
  local format = string.format
  commands.change_color = function()
    options = { format("r=%0.3f, g=%0.3f, b=%0.3f", random(), random(), random()) }
    context.definecolor( {"randomcolor"}, options)
  end
\stopluacode

\startsetups change:color
  \ctxcommand{change_color()}
\stopsetups

\setupbackgrounds
   [page]
   [
     background=color,
     setups=change:color, 
     backgroundcolor=randomcolor,
   ]


% Just to visualize the result
\setuppapersize[A6][A2,landscape]
\setuppaper[nx=5,ny=3]
\setuparranging[XY]


\starttext

\dorecurse{15}{\null\page}

\stoptext
```

which gives
[image]

Answer (score 27):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} % seed for random generator

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{random(0,10000)/10000}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\G}{random(0,10000)/10000}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(0,10000)/10000}%
    \definecolor{bgcolor}{rgb}{\R,\G,\B}%
    \color{bgcolor!40}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
}

\begin{document}

    \foreach \n in {1,...,100}{
        \begin{frame}
            test
        \end{frame}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for curiosity, how did you compose the image?

Comment: The image is just a screenshot of the resulting pdf opened with Preview. No magic :)