# How to use gray colour mode in fill command in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

This seems like a really stupid question, but I cannot find the answer...

I am trying to make a contiguous grid of coloured blocks using Tikz, much like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352495/113430), but in my case, the colours to be filled in are grayscale values in the real number range [0.0,1.0], i.e. the 'gray' colour model listed in the xcolor package documentation.  The values (and, in theory, the figures) are generated programmatically and could be any arbitrary number between 0 and 1 (inclusive), so it won't make sense to use a handful of `definecolor` commands at the start.  Instead, my current plan is to overwrite the fill for each node as my script writes it out to the file.

For a minimum working example, the below produces something that looks like what I want (see the image below it), except I cannot work out how to get the correct sort of grayscale settings.  Using the approach I thought might work, the first three cells just produce white (I suspect it is using the Gray system, with an integer range of [0,255]).  The latter six create the sort of results I'm looking for, but the fill colours are not specified in a useful way.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,minimum size=1cm]
\selectcolormodel{gray}
    \node [fill={gray!0.1}] at (0,0) {};
    \node [fill={gray!0.2}] at (0,-1) {};
    \node [fill={gray!0.3}] at (0,-2) {};
    \node [fill={rgb:black,4;white,8}] at (1,0) {};
    \node [fill={rgb:black,5;white,7}] at (1,-1) {};
    \node [fill={rgb:black,6;white,6}] at (1,-2) {};
    \node [fill={rgb:black,7;white,5}] at (2,0) {};
    \node [fill={rgb:black,8;white,4}] at (2,-1) {};
    \node [fill={rgb:black,9;white,3}] at (2,-2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the MWE]

I have also tried out such commands as `gray:0.1`, or using `\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}` and then something like just `0.1`, but all of those seem to hit compilation errors.

Alternatively, I also tried using the 'matrix' option of Tikz, as below, but that didn't seem to permit any colouring of the grid cells (the visible lines come from using the `node=draw` option).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
    \matrix {
        \node { }; [fill={rgb:black,2;white,10}]; & \node {}; [fill={rgb:black,3;white,9}]; & \node {}; [fill={rgb:black,4;white,8}]; \\
        \node { }; [fill={rgb:black,5;white,7}]; & \node {}; [fill={rgb:black,6;white,6}]; & \node {}; [fill={rgb:black,7;white,5}]; \\
        \node { }; [fill={rgb:black,2;white,10}]; & \node {}; [fill={rgb:black,3;white,9}]; & \node {}; [fill={rgb:black,4;white,8}]; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result from using the second MWE's code]

How can I create a grid of grayscale coloured blocks using Tikz, with gray colour values in the real number range [0.0,1.0] specified individually for each cell?

Comment: You are confusing the gray model of xcolor (used in `colorlet` for example) with the color mixing (the `color!number!color2` notation). To have a grey scale with the second one you need to use `black!xx` where `xx` is in the range 0-100 (the second color is white when not specified)

Comment: I wouldn't even say it's as advanced as confusing the two.  I couldn't find any explanation in the Tikz documentation about specifying grayscale colours inline, so I was just imitating what I saw elsewhere.  Your comment is literally the first explanation of that I have seen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this goes in the right direction. It sets the gray level via `black!<level>`, where `<level>` is an integer that emerges from multiplying the input, which is in `[0,1]`, by `100`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[g/.style={minimum size=1cm,fg=#1},
    fg/.code={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\iFill}{100*#1}%
        \tikzset{fill=black!\iFill}}]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=0pt,row sep=0pt,nodes in empty cells] {
     |[g=0.3]| & |[g=0.6]|\\
     |[g=0.1]| & |[g=0.9]|\\
     |[g=0.5]| & |[g=0.2]|\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many more possibilities, including using a `matrix plot` from `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the use of `.code` and the code inside it, but it seems to work to automatically fix a filling color for every cell in matrix.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mycolor/.code={
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\percent}{(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1)*20+(\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)*5},
        \tikzset{fill=gray!\percent},
        }
    ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, mycolor}
    ]{
    & & & \\
     & & & \\
     & & & \\
     & & & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this should be accepted answer: plain use of TikZ's library `matrix`

Answer (score 0):

Guess what you need is `gray!10` instead of `gray!.1`.

In `xcolor`'s color mix expression, the number is in percents, hence `gray!<n>` means the color from mixing `<n>`% of gray and `1 - <n>%` of white.

In your `gray!.1`, the resulting color is the mix of 0.1% gray and 99.9% white, which is indistinguishable with 100% white.