# Generate random color in way that works with both pdflatex and lualatex

Tags: pdftex, color, luatex, random

Right now, I am generating a random color in pdftex using

```
\definecolor{randomcolor}{RGB}
{
    \pdfuniformdeviate 255,
    \pdfuniformdeviate 255,
    \pdfuniformdeviate 255
}
```

Which works pretty well,
until I try and compile with luatex.

**What is the nicest way to generate random colors (either directly or via generating 3 random numbers), that is compatible across both pdftex and luatex?**

I suspect something involving *pgf* is the answer.
Or maybe just a condition with one branch for pdftex (that looks like the current), and one for luatex (that maybe invokes a tiny snippet of luacode).

Comment: Is the `luatex85` package usable? It brings back all the deleted `\pdf...` macros to `lualatex`

Comment: @daleif yes. Expand that into an answer, with a link to the docs maybe and that would be great. Assuming luatex85 is a no-op or something in pdftex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `luatex85` package does

```
\let\pdfuniformdeviate\uniformdeviate
```

You can thus do `\usepackage{luatex85}` or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\unless\ifdefined\pdfuniformdeviate
  \let\pdfuniformdeviate\uniformdeviate
\fi

\definecolor{randomcolor}{RGB}
{
    \pdfuniformdeviate 255,
    \pdfuniformdeviate 255,
    \pdfuniformdeviate 255
}
\extractcolorspec{randomcolor}\test
\typeout{\test}

\stop
```

This will type out something like

```
{rgb}{0.84706,0.4,0.68234}
```

with both `pdflatex` or `lualatex`. I guess that, when random numbers will be available also in `xelatex`, a common interface will be added to the LaTeX kernel.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the [`lcg`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lcg) package (short for Linear Congruential Generator), that works with all compilers, including `lualatex`. The package provides a command `\rand` to generate a random number and store it in the `rand` counter. For use in `\definecolor` you should convert the counter with `\the\value`.

You can set the bounds of the random generator with the package options `first` and `last`, and optionally change them within the document using the `\reinitrand` command. The default seed is based on the system clock, using the minutes as unit (so the output will change only once per minute). You can also provide a custom seed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[first=1,last=255]{lcg}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\rand\edef\colora{\the\value{rand}}
\rand\edef\colorb{\the\value{rand}}
\rand\edef\colorc{\the\value{rand}}

\definecolor{randomcolor}{RGB}
{
    \colora,
    \colorb,
    \colorc
}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{randomcolor}{Random color: \colora,\colorb,\colorc}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Use `\the\value{rand}` instead of `\arabic`. `\arabic` is a formatting command and there is no garanty that it gives a number (e.g. hebrew and arabic packages often redefine it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the improvement, it didn't occur to me to put `\the` there - edited.

Answer (score 4):

> Based on [Randomly assign background colour for each frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171481/randomly-assign-background-colour-for-each-frame)

Another approach based on `pgf`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifluatex
  \let\pdfrandomseed\randomseed
\fi

\ifxetex
  \pgfmathsetseed{\time}
\else
  \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\fi

\newcommand{\randomcolor}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{rnd}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\G}{rnd}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{rnd}%
    \definecolor{randomcol}{rgb}{\R,\G,\B}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\foreach \n in {1,...,1350}{%
   \randomcolor\color{randomcol}\rule{0.41cm}{0.41cm}\-%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]