# How to show rows of randomly colored circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to have 5 rows of randomly colored circles. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[2][red,fill=red]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw[#1,radius=#2] (0,0) circle ;}%


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The counting problem}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,100}  {\tikzcircle{2pt}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am not sure how to pick the colors at random or how to get the circles to wrap so they fill the space the text would normally fill.

If possible, it would be great if I could pick colors randomly with replacement from a set whose size I can specify. E.g pick the colors randomly with replacement from a set of 10 colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with something like this. Code for `\randomcolor` was taken from [Generate random color in way that works with both pdflatex and lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447066/1952)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\randomcolor}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{random(0,10000)/10000}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\G}{random(0,10000)/10000}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(0,10000)/10000}%
    \definecolor{randomcolor}{rgb}{\R,\G,\B}%
}

\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[1]{\randomcolor\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\fill[randomcolor,radius=#1]circle;}}%


\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} % seed for random generator


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The counting problem}

\foreach \j in {1,2,...,5} {\foreach \i in {1,2,...,10} {\tikzcircle{.05\textwidth}}\\}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update: limited colors**

Following code shows an alternative to select colors from a limited set. The set is defined into a `TikZ` array and the color is selected with a random index.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\mycolors{{"red","green","blue","brown","pink","violet","orange","cyan","yellow"}}
    
\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolorindex}{random(0,8)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{array(\mycolors,\mycolorindex)}%
    \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\fill[\mycolor,radius=#1]circle;}}%

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} % seed for random generator

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The counting problem}

\foreach \j in {1,2,...,5}{\foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{\tikzcircle{.05\textwidth}}\\}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you specify how many different colors there will be? I want to limit it to a small number sometimes so I will get a lot of repeated colors.

Comment: Try `` \newcommand{\randomcolor}{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{random(0,1)/1}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\G}{random(0,1)/1}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(0,1)/1}%
  \definecolor{randomcolor}{rgb}{\R,\G,\B}%
 }``

Comment: @Anush I've updated the code with a new version for limited colors. This example is made with 9 colors, but you can change the number or just select from a shorter list fixing the upper bound at the random selector.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try to play with the parameters of the random number generator, while keeping the same seed.

For example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=5mm} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\randomcolor}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{random(0,1)/2}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\G}{random(0,1)/2}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(0,1)/1}%
    \definecolor{randomcolor}{rgb}{\R,\G,\B}%
}

\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[1]{\randomcolor\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\fill[randomcolor,radius=#1]circle;}}%


%\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} % seed for random generator


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The counting problem}

\foreach \j in {1,2,...,5}{\foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{\noindent\tikzcircle{.05\textwidth}}\\}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

will produce 2x2x2 = 8 different colors. (R= 0 or 0.5, etc.)

[image: fewer colors]

Comment: Can you explicitly specify the number of colours you want?  In this case it is 6 but say I wanted 10 or some other number.